# app.post in parse-server returning an error

Tags: heroku, http-post, parse-server

I am using twilio and trying to post to my `/testing` function in my index.js file, but I get an error `error: {unauthorized}`. I have a feeling it has to do with api keys but I am unsure. I am passing my master key and app id in the header of the request, but I still get the same error. I am posting to https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse/index/test.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://xxxxxxx',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY || 'xxxxxxxx',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xxxxxxx', //
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'xxxxxx', // Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
liveQuery: {
classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
 }
});

var app = express();
var twilio = require('twilio');

var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

app.post('/test', twilio.webhook({ validate: false }), function (req, res) {
console.log("use-sms") //Not printed, get the error "error:{unauthorized}"
from = req.body.From;
to   = req.body.To;
body = req.body.Body;

gatherOutgoingNumber(from, to)
.then(function (outgoingPhoneNumber) {
var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
twiml.message(body, { to: outgoingPhoneNumber });

res.type('text/xml');
res.send(twiml.toString());
 });
});
```